# Finding the closest string match for each string in two dataframe columns

Tags: python, performance, iteration, edit-distance

I was wondering what's the fastest method to compare similarity between two lists of strings (e.g. two dataframes, documents etc.) using levenshtein distance or other procedures.

I am currently using:

```
def wuzzyfuzzy(df1, df2):
    myList = []
    total = len(df1)
    for idx1, df1_str in enumerate(df1.col1):
        myDict = {}
        my_str = ('Progress : ' + str(round((idx1/total)*100,3))+'%')
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(my_str))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        for idx2, df2_str in enumerate(df2.col1):
            s = SequenceMatcher(None, df1_str, df2_str)
            r = s.ratio()
            myDict.update({df2_str:r})
        best_match = max(myDict, key=myDict.get)
        myList.append([df1_str, best_match, myDict[best_match]])

    return myList
```

As the dataframes that are passed to the function have both > 30.000 values, it takes currently around **6 hours** to compare each value in df1 with all other values in df2 to find the best match.

Of course I cleaned the strings as good as possible beforehand (all lowercase, get rid of punctuations etc.)

What's the most efficient way to perfom such task?

Comment: It might help to know what the strings look like.  Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing 30,000 strings against 30,000 other strings is 900 million comparisons.  It's going to take a while.

Run the Python profiler on a small data set to see where it is spending the most time.  So you can focus your efforts.

#### difflib

The documentation for `SequenceMatcher` says it caches information about the second sequence.  So that to compare one string against a bunch of other strings, use `.set_seq2()` to set the one string, and the use `.set_seq()` to check it against each of the other strings.

It also says that calculating `ratio()` is expensive to compute so you might want to use 'quick_ratio()`or`real_quick_ratio()` first.

```
def wuzzyfuzzy(df1, df2):
    myList = []
    total = len(df1)

    s = SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, autojunk=False)

    for idx1, df1_str in enumerate(df1.col1):
        s.set_seq2(df1_str)

        my_str = ('Progress : ' + str(round((idx1/total)*100,3))+'%')
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(my_str))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        best_str2 = ''
        best_ratio = 0

        for idx2, df2_str in enumerate(df2.col1):
            s.set_seq2(df2_str)

            if s.real_quick_ratio() > best_ratio and s.quick_ratio() > best_ratio:
                r = s.ratio()

                if r > best_ratio:
                    best_match = df2_str
                    best_ratio = r

        myList.append([df1_str, best_match, best_ratio])

    return myList
```

You could also consider `difflib.get_close_matches(string, possibilities, n, cutoff)`.  It compares `string` against a list `possibilities` and returns a list of upto `n` that match better than `cutoff`.

```
def wuzzyfuzzy(df1, df2):
    myList = []

    possibilities = list(df2.col1)

    s = SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, autojunk=False)

    for idx1, df1_str in enumerate(df1.col1):
        my_str = ('Progress : ' + str(round((idx1/total)*100,3))+'%')
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(my_str))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # get 1 best match that has a ratio of at least 0.7
        best_match = get_close_matches(df1_str1, possibilities, 1, 0.7)

        s.set_seq(df1_str, best_match) 
        myList.append([df1_str, best_match, s.ratio()])

        return myList
```